# flink unit testing - cannot set the context to process all function

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

assuming that I have this

```
class FooProcess extends ProcessAllWindowFunction[String,String, TimeWindow]{
override def process(context: Context, elements: Iterable[String], out: Collector[String]): Unit = ???
}
```

I want to write some unit tests to the process method but I am having issues mocking the context

```
val context =  mock[Context[FooProcess]]
```

This import fails (`cannot resolve symbol Context`)

```
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.windowing.ProcessAllWindowFunction.Context
```

Any idea / best practices for unit testing in flink ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that the `Context` is inner class of the `ProcessAllWindowFunction` class. In scala inner classes are bound to the outer objects. So, if You want to mock the context and use it to test the `process()` function then you can do something as below:

```
val foo = new FooProcess
val mock = mock[foo.Context]
foo.process(...)
```